# Directory of running script in Fish shell

Tags: bash, fish

I'm trying to get SBT running using the Fish shell. Below is the equivalent Bash script of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

I see in the Fish documentation that `$@` in Bash can be replaced with `$argv` in Fish.
But I cannot see what to replace `dirname $0` with.

Does anyone know the equivalent script in Fish?

Comment: I suggest to edit the question to highlight the $0 conversion to (status -f), that is separate that from the java invocation that is specific to your case. That apart, really useful topic!

Answer (score 5):

$_ only seems to work directly via the reader/command line, or when the script is sourced, for me.

Maybe this will work for you:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar (dirname (status -f))/sbt-launch.jar "$argv"      # fish
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fish` equivalent to this:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar $(dirname $0)/sbt-launch.jar "$@"     # Bash, et al
```

is

```
java -Xmx512M -jar (dirname $_)/sbt-launch.jar "$argv"      # fish
```

Comment: Hey Dennis thanks for the reply. I've got a strange issue though, $_ is always an empty string for me. Any ideas?

Comment: $_ won't work in a script with fish shebang, check otherchirps' answer instead.

Comment: @dennis-williamson can you provide an example of that working? Here's an example of $_ not being available in a script using fish 1.23.1 https://gist.github.com/4157106

Comment: @anddam: Hmmm... It doesn't work for me when Fish is my *interactive* shell, but it does work when my interactive shell is Bash, Korn or Zsh - even when the shebang is calling for fish! It even works (badly) when dash is the interactive shell! Each of these (parent) shells results in a slightly different value. By the way, Bash, for one, does not export `$_` so I don't know how Fish is getting it. `help fish` in Fish says "which is the name of the currently running command." and it is updated. Try `pwd; echo $_` at the Fish command line. Now replace `pwd` with another command or string several

Comment: ...together with semicolons. The `echo` always outputs the name of the first command on the line. This works at the command line, but not in a script apparently.

Comment: I can reproduce that behavior, it is a bit inconsistent from an user's perspective. My initial comment to your answer was aimed at this specific question: an user running fish that is writing a script to start a program cannot use $_ and has to use what @otherchirps suggested instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Use `status` Builtin and `argv` Variable

The fish shell uses the `status` command to return information about a number of things, including the filename or directory of the currently-running script. It also uses the *argv* variable rather than Bash's `$@`. Additionally, fish's variables are lists, so you don't want to quote them the way you do in Bash unless you're trying to treat all the contents of the list as a single string.

Assuming you're running this from a file such as `foo.fish`, the way to do this would be to include the following line in your script file:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar (status dirname)/sbt-launch.jar $argv
```